# wordpress customize control panel doesn't work after offline migration

Tags: php, wordpress

I recetly migrate offline wordpress custom web template to online server via plugin  All-in-One WP Migration. Everything works fine, except customize control panel. There is fatal erorr in debug log:

```
[09-Nov-2018 11:56:41 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Customize_Code_Editor_Control' not found in /wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php:5317

Stack trace:
#0 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): WP_Customize_Manager->register_controls(Object(WP_Customize_Manager))
#1 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php(926): do_action('customize_regis...', Object(WP_Customize_Manager))
#4 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): WP_Customize_Manager->wp_loaded('')
#5 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#6 wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php on line 5317
```

I tried some tuts like .htaccess problem, increase upload memory, deactivete all plugins or overwrite class-wp-customize-manager.php with original wp installation file.

Nothing worked.

Any idea? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your custom fuction class within function bind to 'customize_register' action because Class WP_Customize_Control is loaded only when theme customizer is acutally used.
Sample code:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'my_customize_register' );
function my_customize_register($wp_customize) {
   //class definition must be within my_customie_register function
   class your_customize_fuction extends WP_Customize_Control { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Really aprreciate it. Sorry to be a little bit ignorant, but i honestly have no idea, what should i do right know (kind a noob in php). Is it possible to tell me step by step what code, where to put it and other steps to fix it? If you need some more my code, just ask.